# input parameter 'scope' is not valid. scope https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All is not valid

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Getting error while requesting access token for EWS oauth2 v2.0 with client_credintials grant type.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token

• Request Headers:

• Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

• Postman-Token:"27a57c92-a5aa-47b7-8121-01ceb18d1d50"

• User-Agent:"PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"

• Host:"login.microsoftonline.com"


• Request Body:

• client_id:"***********************"

• client_secret:"*********************"

• scope:"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All"

• grant_type:"client_credentials"
```

Response Body:

> • error:"invalid_scope" • error_description:"AADSTS70011: The provided
>   request must include a 'scope' input parameter. The provided value for
>   the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope
>   https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All is not valid. Trace
>   ID: 9e6cbb7a-34ed-4797-b650-4c99becb3b00 Correlation ID:
>   c2295999-9cc2-4ba3-a12b-a26f3fc10d08 Timestamp: 2019-01-25 06:17:43Z"
>   • error_codes: • 0:70011 • timestamp:"2019-01-25 06:17:43Z" •
>   trace_id:"9e6cbb7a-34ed-4797-b650-4c99becb3b00"
>   correlation_id:"c2295999-9cc2-4ba3-a12b-a26f3fc10d08"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `scope` should be `https://outlook.office365.com/.default`, then it will work fine. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret).

[image]

Comment: Yeah, you gotta use .default with client credentials grant. I assume it's because the token will always contain whatever permissions have been granted to the app.